# How to validate opendkim generated RSA keys

Tags: openssl, ssh-keys, rsa, opendkim

I'm trying to diagnose OpenDKIM validation errors (see [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1079331/how-to-diagnose-opendkim-rsa-signatures?noredirect=1#comment1409002_1079331)). Way down in the belly of the beast, I'm at the point where I'm trying to make sure the keys generated are actually correct.

I'm generating my keys with `opendkim-genkey -r -d example.com`. This generates two files. One is an RSA private key (file `default.private`):

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and one generates the DKIM DNS entry, which I assume contains the public key:

```
default._domainkey  IN  TXT ( "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; s=email; "
      "p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDJy9S18vHtrIQNep9PogJfrKNLKKf2VSOvUwOzItlWkY3cRCFxscSNjfC4QHREcMeUuNO78wvQ+oOk+exLdyl2BggcA659Wi6v8X/+awLXpa9sB6viGPi8Zx560GbZu6jGLlEzcOaGDCYqdUxZIdAaOICDORFa3XAywHi87eQPMwIDAQAB" )  ; ----- DKIM key default for example.com
```

I'm assuming the "p=" entry is the public key, but if it is, I can't figure out how to verify if they match. I thought I could do this with `ssh-keygen -y -f default.private`, however, the output of that is distinctly different than what's in the "p=" section of the DNS entry (it's not even the same length):

```
# ssh-keygen -y -f default.private 
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAAAgQDJy9S18vHtrIQNep9PogJfrKNLKKf2VSOvUwOzItlWkY3cRCFxscSNjfC4QHREcMeUuNO78wvQ+oOk+exLdyl2BggcA659Wi6v8X/+awLXpa9sB6viGPi8Zx560GbZu6jGLlEzcOaGDCYqdUxZIdAaOICDORFa3XAywHi87eQPMw==
```

So, what's going on here? Is ssh-keygen not the right way to do this (maybe I should be doing something with OpenSSL?)? Is "p=" not the public key? Or, in fact, do my private and public keys not match?

Thanks!

PS, as a perhaps unrelated aside, what I'm assuming to be the public key generated by opendkim is always the same for the first 34 characters — `MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQ` — and always ends in `IDAQAB`.

Comment: SSH keys are different.  See a good answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/1679344/for-valid-pem-i-get-unable-to-load-private-key-by-openssh?noredirect=1#comment2577724_1679344

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compare the modulus of both, as follows:

Grab the public key from your DNS record.  This is the string within the `p=`, as you say.  Be aware that it is sometimes returned as two strings, which you'll need to join.  You only need the contents, less the double quotes.  Save this locally, as `public.key.b64`.

Convert to DER format with:

```
openssl enc -base64 -d -in public.key.b64 -out public.key
```

View the modulus of this public key with:

```
openssl rsa -pubin -inform DER -in public.key -noout -modulus
```

View the modulus of your private key with:

```
openssl rsa -in private.key -noout -modulus
```

The output of both will be similar to the following and must match:

```
Modulus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
```